# Change a row when "now()" is a specific datetime. Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

I've this column `information_release_counter`. And another one `confirmed`.

I update my `information_release_counter` so :

```
serializer_id.information_release_counter = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=48)
```

I would like that when

`datetime.datetime.now() - serializer_id.information_release_counter == 0`

`serializer.confirmed` was "True". But it should happen automatically.

I don't know if there's a "watcher" or something like that.

I was reading the `celery task` and `eta`, but I don't have a clue how I can use it. :)

I'm trying this:

```
@celery.task
def set_confirmed_death(user_object):
    user_object.death_confirmed = True
    user_object.save()
```

with this:

```
set_confirmed_death(use, countdown=15)
```

Just for testing, and it doesn't work. Don't know what's wrong. I get this error:

> TypeError: set_confirmed_death() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'countdown'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer.

I didn't know I needed more things than just a celery...

I followed this tutorial:
[First Steps](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps)

So I installed a worked.

Then, I clarify some questions with this post:

[stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806428/celery-error-result-get-times-out)

And finally I adapted for Django with this tutorial:

[Celery in Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

so, in my views.py:

```
serializer_id.information_release_counter = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=48)
set_confirmed_death.apply_async([serializer_id.id], eta=serializer_id.information_release_counter)
```

I got an error with `datetime.datetime.now` but it works properly with "now()".

And then `init.py`, `celery.py` and `tasks.py` exactly as they described in the tutorial (of course, with my own `set_confirmed_death` function)

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value of `information_release_counter` to use `datetime.datetime.now`, not `datetime.datetime.now()`. The latter will always get the current datetime, which doesn't appear to be what you want (since the goalpost always changes for the other column value).

Then, create a Celery task to accept the PK of the object with the attrs in question. In calling the task, pass in the value of `information_release_counter` as the `countdown` in seconds.

The task can look-up the object, change the value of `confirmed`, and save it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! ```serializer_id.information_release_counter = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=48)``` makes what I want :). For example, I did it at 19:58 and now I've there ```"2017-02-05 19:58:17.950403+01"``` so, it works. But I would love, that at February 5th 19:58 this happens ```serializer_id.confirmed = True```

Comment: Yeah, but will that ever be true since `now()` always gives a new datetime?

Comment: Well, so the value for `information_release_counter` won't change after being set.

You will need something to set `confirmed` once your criteria are met however.

Comment: yeah, that's the point. How can I say it to ```confirmed``` automatically. I mean, I set counter for 2 days, and in 48 hours, confirmed should be set to ```True```.

Comment: So, you can pass the value of the counter into a celery task (in seconds?) as the countdown with the ID of the object to change (whatever model `confirmed` is on). The celery task would look up the object, change confirmed to True and save. I've updated my answer.

Comment: hmm I don't know what I'm doing wrong...
I did it so: ```set_confirmed_death(serializer_id, countdown=15)``` just for testing, and then.. ```@celery.task
def set_confirmed_death(user_object):
    user_object.death_confirmed = True
    user_object.save()``` and I get this error : ```TypeError: set_confirmed_death() got an unexpected keyword argument 'countdown'```

Comment: You need to call `apply_async` for the task. Consult the Celery docs http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html

Comment: Thanks for your "patience". I got this error ```kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused``` :( I use it so now ```set_confirmed_death.apply_async(args=[serializer_id.id], countdown=15)``` Should I install something, or do anything in the settings.py? I hoped it was easier :D

Comment: I'd check your settings. Sorry, this is a little outside the scope of your question...